# Simulate a start up: Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, startup

I coded an app which starts at the system start up and starts a service which is written in the code. The code is working fine and the service is getting started when the app is installed on a real android device but not on an emulator. I do not have a real device always handy. Any idea how to simulate a start up in an emulator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting emulator simulates a boot up. Didn't know it earlier as I was missing the `Toast` which I had put up on the boot up for some reasons I don't know. When tried on a faster machine, the same code worked like charm. :)

Answer (score 3):

I just found a way to simulate a start-up without having to stop-and-start the emulator. Go to the DDMS perspective (if you are using Eclipse) and "stop" the `android.core` process. This process respawns (you would know this if you have ever owned a HTC where that essential process seemed to stop wayyy to often) and that process of respawning will effectively reboot the emulator- i.e the BOOT event is fired.