# What is the simulate boot complete intent order?

Tags: android

Use adb order send a intent, simulate the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED intent, then I can debug no need reboot my phone every time, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you asking how to get the system to fire an ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED intent without actually rebooting, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532313/simulate-a-start-up-android-emulator It would seem that stopping the android.core process may help you...

Comment: I remember have a adb order, like "adb shell broadcast intent", but i forget the specific params, can simulate the device boot intent.

Comment: Your question needs heavy editing, but I understand what you're saying now. You use the Activity Manager, check my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should send the intent you want...

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n your.package.name/your.intent.receiver.class
```

Usage

```
am start [-D] [-W] [-P <FILE>] [--start-profiler <FILE>]
       [--R COUNT] [-S] [--opengl-trace]
       [--user <USER_ID> | current] <INTENT>
am startservice [--user <USER_ID> | current] <INTENT>
am force-stop [--user <USER_ID> | all | current] <PACKAGE>
am kill [--user <USER_ID> | all | current] <PACKAGE>
am kill-all
am broadcast [--user <USER_ID> | all | current] <INTENT>
am instrument [-r] [-e <NAME> <VALUE>] [-p <FILE>] [-w]
       [--user <USER_ID> | current]
       [--no-window-animation] <COMPONENT>
am profile start [--user <USER_ID> current] <PROCESS> <FILE>
am profile stop [--user <USER_ID> current] [<PROCESS>]
am dumpheap [--user <USER_ID> current] [-n] <PROCESS> <FILE>
am set-debug-app [-w] [--persistent] <PACKAGE>
am clear-debug-app
am monitor [--gdb <port>]
am screen-compat [on|off] <PACKAGE>
am display-size [reset|WxH]
am display-density [reset|DENSITY]
am to-uri [INTENT]
am to-intent-uri [INTENT]
am switch-user <USER_ID>
am stop-user <USER_ID>

am start: start an Activity.  Options are:
    -D: enable debugging
    -W: wait for launch to complete
    --start-profiler <FILE>: start profiler and send results to <FILE>
    -P <FILE>: like above, but profiling stops when app goes idle
    -R: repeat the activity launch <COUNT> times.  Prior to each repeat,
        the top activity will be finished.
    -S: force stop the target app before starting the activity
    --opengl-trace: enable tracing of OpenGL functions
    --user <USER_ID> | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
        specified then run as the current user.

am startservice: start a Service.  Options are:
    --user <USER_ID> | current: Specify which user to run as; if not
        specified then run as the current user.

am force-stop: force stop everything associated with <PACKAGE>.
    --user <USER_ID> | all | current: Specify user to force stop;
        all users if not specified.

am kill: Kill all processes associated with <PACKAGE>.  Only kills.
  processes that are safe to kill -- that is, will not impact the user
  experience.
    --user <USER_ID> | all | current: Specify user whose processes to kill;
        all users if not specified.

am kill-all: Kill all background processes.

am broadcast: send a broadcast Intent.  Options are:
    --user <USER_ID> | all | current: Specify which user to send to; if not
        specified then send to all users.

am instrument: start an Instrumentation.  Typically this target <COMPONENT>
  is the form <TEST_PACKAGE>/<RUNNER_CLASS>.  Options are:
    -r: print raw results (otherwise decode REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT).  Use with
        [-e perf true] to generate raw output for performance measurements.
    -e <NAME> <VALUE>: set argument <NAME> to <VALUE>.  For test runners a
        common form is [-e <testrunner_flag> <value>[,<value>...]].
    -p <FILE>: write profiling data to <FILE>
    -w: wait for instrumentation to finish before returning.  Required for
        test runners.
    --user <USER_ID> | current: Specify user instrumentation runs in;
        current user if not specified.
    --no-window-animation: turn off window animations will running.

am profile: start and stop profiler on a process.  The given <PROCESS> argument
  may be either a process name or pid.  Options are:
    --user <USER_ID> | current: When supplying a process name,
        specify user of process to profile; uses current user if not specified.

am dumpheap: dump the heap of a process.  The given <PROCESS> argument may
  be either a process name or pid.  Options are:
    -n: dump native heap instead of managed heap
    --user <USER_ID> | current: When supplying a process name,
        specify user of process to dump; uses current user if not specified.

am set-debug-app: set application <PACKAGE> to debug.  Options are:
    -w: wait for debugger when application starts
    --persistent: retain this value

am clear-debug-app: clear the previously set-debug-app.

am bug-report: request bug report generation; will launch UI
    when done to select where it should be delivered.
am monitor: start monitoring for crashes or ANRs.
    --gdb: start gdbserv on the given port at crash/ANR

am screen-compat: control screen compatibility mode of <PACKAGE>.

am display-size: override display size.

am display-density: override display density.

am to-uri: print the given Intent specification as a URI.

am to-intent-uri: print the given Intent specification as an intent: URI.

am switch-user: switch to put USER_ID in the foreground, starting
  execution of that user if it is currently stopped.

am stop-user: stop execution of USER_ID, not allowing it to run any
  code until a later explicit switch to it.

<INTENT> specifications include these flags and arguments:
    [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
    [--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
    [--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
    [--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
    [--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]
    [--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE> ...]
    [--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...]
    [--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
    [--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
    [--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
    [--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]]
    [-n <COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>]
    [--grant-read-uri-permission] [--grant-write-uri-permission]
    [--debug-log-resolution] [--exclude-stopped-packages]
    [--include-stopped-packages]
    [--activity-brought-to-front] [--activity-clear-top]
    [--activity-clear-when-task-reset] [--activity-exclude-from-recents]
    [--activity-launched-from-history] [--activity-multiple-task]
    [--activity-no-animation] [--activity-no-history]
    [--activity-no-user-action] [--activity-previous-is-top]
    [--activity-reorder-to-front] [--activity-reset-task-if-needed]
    [--activity-single-top] [--activity-clear-task]
    [--activity-task-on-home]
    [--receiver-registered-only] [--receiver-replace-pending]
    [--selector]
    [<URI> | <PACKAGE> | <COMPONENT>]
```

Comment: yes, I use "Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" before, so cause no work. thanks your answer.